# Noach - Miracle or Animal Psychologist?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach, noach-noah-the-man

[Breishit 6:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=114&hilite=) says that there were three levels in Noach's ark. Rash"I explains that the top level was for Noach and his family; the middle for the animals, and the bottom for waste.

That implies that all the animals were together in the same level. Some animals are predators of other animals. Did Noach attempt to separate the species so that they wouldn't harm each other? If so, how would he have known about animal behavior for every species? Or was it just miraculous that animals didn't eat or harm each other?

Comment: G-d _did_ bring all of the animals in pairs to the Ark in the first place, and since they didn't attack each other there, I'd assume they didn't attack each other in the Ark.

Comment: By the way, Rashi is just quoting a baraisa that is mentioned in [Sanhedrin 108b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.108b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Answer (score 3):

> Did Noach attempt to separate the species so that they wouldn't harm each other? If so, how would he have known about animal behavior for every species?

Actually, he separated *all* types from one another, not only predators and prey [, and thus did not need to know animal behavior in order to decide on living arrangements].

Source: [*Rashi*](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.14?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.6.14.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) to verse 14.

Answer (score 0):

Miracle. I don't think this requires textual proof as Noah's involvement with bringing together species from the entire planet has never been replicated even by half the quantity by an animal psychologist or other profession that works with animals or information about animals.